# Orchard CMS create theme view for my content type

Tags: orchardcms

I am using orchard cms with the bootstrap theme.

I have created a content type: **House**

it contains **FIELDS**

- image (media picker field)
- Property Type (taxonomy field)
- Location (taxonomy field)

It has **PARTS**

- common
- body
- publish later
- Title
- Autoroute

I want queries of houses and be able to choose the view/ layout for them

e.g. layout called **HouseList** (for sidebars mainly) which will render: title, image and link to house, possible location and type  but with out the links as defaulted. And then a fullDetails layout and a image only layout (so i can show a jquery image reel a widget say in a quadzone) **How can i do all this please**, i have tried in view Content-House.cshtml etc but i cant access the details model.content to choose what to display.

Im sure when i get the idea of how to do 1 i should be able to sort the rest. I have read documentation etc but there are so many different ways, ie placement file, change the parts, contents, create classes to handle display etc. **sureley i am  missing something simple** like create a view for each list i want eg. houue-list, house-details, house-imageONly and then manipulate content.

**Please help** i have been trying different things for getting this site running for weeks and not getting very far. Examples would be fantastic but i have searched google for hours and found similar but nothing with enough details for a meer beginer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of doing that is placement to move things around and alternate templates for the different parts and fields. You can specialize placement and alternates with the display type, which is Summary when rendering in a list such as what a projection returns, and Detail for the detail view. More info on placement can be found here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info and on alternates here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Now if you prefer to completely take over the rendering and do without placement, here are a few posts that may help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/31/so-you-don-t-want-to-use-placement-info.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Been away for the weekend. Will have a look through these links (i hace already scanned these before). Are there any theme example projects anywhere for reference using the projections and alternatives. I would of thought what i am doing is common place and simple.

Comment: It is common place and simple, which is why I was able to give you those links.

Comment: ok thanks. I think your blog links of not using the placement file look easier to follow as i tried the placement file with no success. Are there no downloadable examples you know of. ie other themes in orchard that do the above i can play around with. Thanks for you help and comments they are much appreciated.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping for too much i guess. It would be good, when tutorial/ information screencasts etc are added to orchard that the code is made available, this would make things far easier for new people using orchard.